# Created copy taking too much free space

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I found a problem using `robocopy` in PowerShell. I used this tool to backup files from one disk (around 220GB) using command:

```
robocopy $source $destination /s /mt:8
```

The problem is that created copy took a lot of free space in the destination location (I stopped making backup when it reached around 850GB). Does anyone know why it has happened?

Comment: Does this happen every time you use robocopy? Is it reproducible?

Comment: I cannot reproduce it. I used it to backup the disk which had damaged partition that was restored before, but it stopped working after few days, so making a copy was important for me. But I have no idea why it created a backup taking (at least, cause I have stopped it at some point) 4x of space it took in the source. Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure, sorry. Can you see what files it was creating that took so much space?

Comment: they are basically the same they were in the source (when I compared it), but when I try to count the size of the backup folder it shows ~850GB.

Comment: Weird. Can you use a tool like [WinDirStat](https://windirstat.info/) to find out what is taking up the extra space?

Comment: May be there're some loops involved
`Ability to skip NTFS junction points which can cause copying failures because of infinite loops`

Try to run with /XJ flag or simply list/log what files are copied to check for loops

Comment: I will try to. I noticed that robocopy creates hidden files, but I will change their attributes to make them all visible and let You know. Thank You for Your time and help.

Comment: But do You know any fast way to find duplicates or such files that caused the loops? It might be quite tought to find all of them in 850 GB of files for me manually

Comment: Yeah, there were infinite loops which I found using WinDirStat. Mostly it were Application Data/Documments and Settings/Users folders. Once again big big thanks :)

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers posted comment as an answer, so it can be marked as a solution for other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be there're some loops involved.
`robocopy` has

> Ability to skip NTFS junction points which can cause copying failures because of infinite loops

Try to run with `/XJ` flag or simply list/log what files are copied to check for loops

See [robocopy help](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx]) and 
[post about it](https://coderwall.com/p/vtcrlg/avoid-robocopy-infinite-loop-with-xj)

**UP** For those who faces same problem:

> there were infinite loops which I found using WinDirStat. Mostly it were Application Data/Documments and Settings/Users folders